# Bootstrap 3 and Liferay conflict class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, liferay

i face some conflict using bootstrap 3 and liferay framework for example the navbar class stop in the framework when we put the main bootstrap style .

I need to limit scope of bootstrap using unique class on body

any help

Comment: Which Liferay version are you using?... Liferay 6.2 already has bootstrap (2.3)

Answer (score 3):

Liferay 6.2, out of the box, uses bootstrap 2.3 (see the [reason behind this](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/the-nitty-gritty-theme-improvements-and-bootstrap-in-liferay-6-6)) and conflicts with bootstrap 3 are (kind of) expected.

In order to get started creating a bs-2.3 theme, you might want to check [Juan Gonzalez's blog](https://www.liferay.com/web/juan.gonzalez/blog/-/blogs/using-existing-bootstrap-themes-in-liferay-part-ii-) (released today, just in time). In case you insist on integrating bootstrap 3 with Liferay 6.2, you'll have to do a lot more work than with 2.3. To "face some conflict" is not quite a sufficient explanation for whatever you're experiencing. And if bs3-integration would be as easy as mitigating some conflict you face, trust me, it would have long been done.